# .htaccess multiple domains in public_html with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, passenger

I'm using a shared hosting account which allows me to host multiple domains, but they must all be within the same public_html folder.  The "add-on" domains seem to work just fine, but I'm trying to get my primary domain to work properly.  It is a Rails app, being hosted through Phusion Passenger.

My current mapping is as such:

```
primarydomain.com ---> ~/public_html/primarydomain/
addondomain1.com  ---> ~/public_html/addondomain1/
addondomain2.com  ---> ~/public_html/addondomain2/
```

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primarydomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /primarydomain/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ primarydomain/ [L]
```

which is based on recommendations from the hosting company.  I don't worry with the add-on domains because the host automatically links those up properly through other configuration tools.  I just need to make the primary one be hosted from a subdirectory.

The problem is that when I try to set up my rails app so that it maps like such

```
http://primarydomain.com --> ~/public_html/primarydomain/ --> ~/rails_apps/primary/public
```

It always fails giving me the following error in the log file:

```
Started GET "/primarydomain/" for 11.22.33.44 at 2014-01-11 21:58:29 -0700
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/primarydomain"):
...
```

Any thoughts to how to resolve this?